# How to track individual objects, that are out of order, and then Joining() the consecutive ones?

Tags: c#, arrays, azure-storage, value-type, azure-blob-storage

I'll start by saying is going to be a little tougher than blindly joining `byte[]` together.

My big picture goal is to optimize an application that currently uploads many 512byte pages to a web server (Azure Page Blob), and reduce that to a single large upload of 4Megs or less.  See the links at the bottom of this question for more background as to why.

> The short answer to why: This optimization will increase speed (fewer IOs) and save money over the long term by using Azure sparse files

**Now for the details:**

The class will need to

- Accept data and store it ( data as defined as `alignment start`, `alignment stop`, and the accompanying payload.
- After N pieces of data arrive, or an `event` occurs, `ProcessData()`. This means it's time to assemble the data according to the boundaries (the stop value of `blob1` must align with the start value of `blob2`)
- Consecutive data may actually arrive out of order.
- Non consecutive data is defined as when the calling app does not send it before `processData()` occurs.  In addition, if the entire 512 byte range == Zero, then that gets special handing, and is treated as non-consecutive.
- We're dealing with types of byte[], so efficient lists may be complicated here. I'd like to avoid unneeded copies and expansions of the array.

Make sense?  (like mud, I hope not)

The closest I've come so far is writing the method signature:  (lame I know)

```
// This can't be bigger than 4Mb, or smaller than 512
byte[] BigBlobToUpload = new byte[];

    /// <summary>
    /// Collects consecutive data ranges that will be uploaded
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="NameOfTarget">The name of the target (unique per host)</param>
    /// <param name="range">The data to be collected, in 512K multiples</param>
    /// <param name="offsetToTransfer">The "start point" or offset of the data stored in range to be included. Almost always 0.</param>
    /// <param name="sizeToTransfer">The length, or end of the range to include.  Almost always 512.</param>
    /// <param name="cloudOffset">The location this data should be placed in the BigBlobToUpload  global var for eventual upload</param>

private void AddToQueue(string NameOfTarget, byte[] range, int offsetToTransfer, int sizeToTransfer, int cloudOffset)
{

}
```

I just need someone to give me a direction on how to track these things efficently ... I can handle it from there.  Even an abstract direction would help

> Can someone put me in the right conceptual direction on how I should
>   track, and *conditionally* join consecutive data ranges?

Not to mention I'm trying to have efficient logic that only expands, or copies the array when needed.

Comment: Can you explain: "This is a little tougher than blindly joining byte[] together, because the application may skip a range, to take advantage of Azure's sparse file system. (writing zeros is never needed, and never billable)" ?

Comment: @GianT971 I need to skip, and not upload, every time I get all zeros on a 512 aligned byte boundary.  This can occur by either the host writing all zeros or by simply omitting the data, and not calling my function.  That is why I think I need to track the start/endpoints of every 512 byte page... and then iterate through each sent page, concatenate and send. I'm not sure how to track this (or begin).

Comment: Related [Azure Page Blob Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2010/04/11/using-windows-azure-page-blobs-and-how-to-efficiently-upload-and-download-page-blobs.aspx)

Comment: Interesting. So your range can be subdivided into 512 byte chunks, and any chunk which would be all zeroes would simply be dropped, is that correct?

Comment: Essentially, but since the host may want to actually erase saved data, I'll issue a special `page clear` header to erase that range.  I imagine I'll track consecutive page clears with the same pattern I use to track valid data.  The resulting action would only be different.

Comment: `byte[]` is not a value type.

Comment: @JimMischel Just fixed... thanks (I wasn't sure if it was)

Comment: Related: A good tutorial on Page Blobs by Brad Calder is [half way through this presentation](http://www.microsoftpdc.com/2009/SVC14)