# Defending against race conditions in System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-4.0, race-condition, concurrentdictionary

The .NET ConcurrentDictionary is susceptible to a race condition that may cause unexpected data as explained [at the bottom of this MSDN article.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997369)  I'm assuming that there are several factors to take into account.

**Q:** How should I write code that is not vulnerable to that race condition that may cause data loss?

In my scenario I have an input stream that has an always increasing index (n++).  My thought is that I could [detect missing data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10565487/328397) if the race condition occurs and re-send it.  On the other hand, there may be a better way to do this that I'm unaware of.

Comment: Avoid GetOrAdd() and AddOrUpdate() ?

Comment: The answer depend on what you will to do. What type of task you have?

Comment: @gabba - My task is to read security log data from various sources.  Each log entry has an ever increasing index.  See updated question/link for more info

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a general pitfall with concurrent collections (not limited to .net) that people have to be aware of, which is that **individual operations may be thread-safe, but sequences of operations are not atomic**. What I mean by this is the following: assume this scenario, where I have a concurrent collection with a `Check` and an `Add` operation, both atomic.

What I want to do is check if a value exists and if not, add it. So I can write this:

```
if(!collection.Check(value)) 
{
    collection.Add(value);
}
```

Although both operations are atomic, the above sequence is not, as a thread may be interrupted between the check and the add by another thread, which leads to inconsistent results. Thus, the entire sequence should be made atomic by wrapping it in a `lock` statement for example.

```
lock(locker)
{
   if(!collection.Check(value)) 
   {
       collection.Add(value);
   }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't the lock cause a huge performance hit? (vs SpinLock).  Would it be better if it's possible to detect missing data and just retransmit it when the dataloss occurs?

Comment: @makerofthings7: Yes, it can be a performance problem in apps that require very high performance and alternative methods can be used, like a lock-less version or a spin lock, since the actual code protected is rather small.

Comment: I think more optimal to use double checked locking.
if(!collection.Check(value)) 
   {
lock(locker)
{
   if(!collection.Check(value)) 
   {
       collection.Add(value);
   }
}
}

Comment: @Gabba thanks for the tip on Double Checked Locking... I'm learning about it now. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking